# Behavior of placement new and uninitialized_fill()

Tags: c++

I see placement new used in the following implementation of `uninitialized_fill`.  Does anyone know the underlying implementation of placement new or where to find it in g++?

I'm assuming the operator takes a pointer to where the object should be placed and a reference to `Value(value)` which is an rvalue after invoking the copy constructor?

Thanks

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
void uninitialized_fill(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type Value;
    ForwardIt current = first;
    try {
        for (; current != last; ++current) {
            ::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*current))) Value(value);
        }
    }  catch (...) {
        for (; first != current; ++first) {
            first->~Value();
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: The new-expression is part of the language, not a library feature (and not an operator either). You can read about its behaviour in the language standard document

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new

Comment: Thanks reading it now.  Curious why https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax shows new as overloaded operators.

Comment: @notaorb C++ has `new` expressions and operator `new`, which are different things, as confusing as that is. A `new` expression is using `new` to create an object as in `new T;`. It allocates memory, invoking the `new` operator of that type if it has one and then calls that type's constructor, if it has one. Placement `new` doesn't use any `new` operator because doesn't need to allocate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) constructs an object at a specified address, yes.

In the expression `::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*current))) Value(value);`, `*current` returns a reference to an element in the specified iterator range, then the address of that element is being casted to `void*` and passed to `placement-new`, which then constructs a new `Value` type (the `value_type` of the iterator) at that address, passing the input `value` to that type's copy constructor.

There is no rvalue being used in this code.  `Value(value)` is not an rvalue being passed to `placement-new`.  `Value` is the type that `placement-new` constructs, with `value` as input to the `Value's` constructor.  Maybe the code would have made more sense if `Value` has been named something more like `ValueType` or `TypeToConstruct` instead.

A `new (address) Type(params)` expression is similar to a `new Type(params)` expression, just with the extra `address` parameter as input.